# How to convert key-value object array into 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let th = ['name', 'id', 'class']
    
let arr = [
    { 'name' : 'a', 'class':'7', 'id':'1' },
    { 'name' : 'b', 'class':'7', 'id':'2' },
    { 'name' : 'b', 'class':'7', 'id':'3' },
    { 'name' : 'd', 'class':'7', 'id':'4' }
]
    
/* final array what is look like */
    
let finalArr = [
    ['a', '1', '7'],
    ['b', '2', '7'],
    ['c', '3', '7'],
    ['d', '4', '7']
]
```

How can I create this array without using `forEach` and `map`? This is a sample data, but in reality there are more than 10k data at a time so `forEach` is not a good option.

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the data if you want that array as your final output, and `.map()` is the correct tool for that (a `for` loop would most likely be faster, but not really by a noticeable amount). If you don't want to iterate your entire data set, then you could consider only converting the object when the value is accessed/needed, otherwise, you might need to consider changing the source of this data or using smaller chunks of data.

Comment: I need this data to print a pdf print, So if I use foreach it take s a long to compile all the data, I am trying to create a dynamic data loop so that I just have to pass the key, and system will auto-select their respective value from an array

Comment: I fail to see how a for(each) loop is not a good option due to the amount of data. If you want to convert the data structure, you have to iterate through all the data one way or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in the third row, fixed here:

```js
let th = ['name', 'id', 'class'];

let arr = [
    { 'name': 'a', 'class': '7', 'id': '1' },
    { 'name': 'b', 'class': '7', 'id': '2' },
    { 'name': 'c', 'class': '7', 'id': '3' },
    { 'name': 'd', 'class': '7', 'id': '4' }
];

const transformedArr = arr.map(row => th.map(name => row[name]));
console.log(transformedArr);
```

A potentially faster one, but actually slower up to 2x times than the above solution (tested in node.js / Chrome with 40000000 items in the `arr`, in Firefox seems the same, but it hangs on that amount of data):

```js
let th = ['name', 'id', 'class'];

let arr = [
    { 'name': 'a', 'class': '7', 'id': '1' },
    { 'name': 'b', 'class': '7', 'id': '2' },
    { 'name': 'c', 'class': '7', 'id': '3' },
    { 'name': 'd', 'class': '7', 'id': '4' }
];

const transformedArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < th.length; j++) {
        item.push(arr[i][th[j]]);
    }
    transformedArr.push(item);
}

console.log(transformedArr);
```

Comment: You are overloading the `len` variable of the outer loop in the inner loop. And that's not the usual syntax for for-loops.

Comment: You should go with the usual `let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++`. Same syntax for the inner loop.

Comment: @Drarig29 The `len` is local to the each loop so no problem here opposite to the `i` in the outer loop. When you cache an array's length property in a variable a loop iterates a bit faster (especially such optimization good for Firefox) since the object property access is a bit slower.

Comment: First, yes `len` is local so there is no conflict. But variable overloading just means that you use the same name in a scope and its child scope. It works but that's a bad practice in general. Second, what you are doing is premature optimization, and you shouldn't give this to beginners without actual benchmarks and _proofs_ that it's faster. Here is an example of someone concluding that it's not faster: https://techformist.com/for-loop-array-length-cache-javascript/

Comment: @Drarig29 cool down, man, I've accepted your code, though I don't care about variable overloading in *that particular case*. Thanks for the link I guess my benchmarks are outdated at least in Chrome. Also actually I've benchmarked the both solutions with 40000000 array items and edited the post - the second solution is slower though maybe 3 years ago it would be faster. The benchmarks always change from a version to a version of a browser.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to sound mean ^^

Answer (score 1):

You may be surprised by the performance of `Array.map`/`Array.forEach` (especially *map*). Here are performance tests for different approaches:

```js
const arr4Test = [...Array(10000)].map((_, i) => ({name: `a`, class: 1, id: i}));
let finalArr = [];

// for ... of
let perf = performance.now();
for (let obj of arr4Test) {
  finalArr.push(Object.values(obj));
}
perf = (performance.now() - perf).toFixed(5);
console.log(`for ... of ${JSON.stringify(finalArr.slice(0, 3))} ... ${perf}ms`);

// classic loop
perf = performance.now();
finalArr.length = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr4Test.length; i += 1) {
  let tmpArr = [];
  
  for (let key in arr4Test[i]) {
    tmpArr.push(arr4Test[i][key])
  }
  
  finalArr.push(tmpArr);
}

perf = (performance.now() - perf).toFixed(5);
console.log(`classic loop ${JSON.stringify(finalArr.slice(0, 3))} ... ${perf}ms`);

// map
perf = performance.now();
finalArr = arr4Test.map(Object.values);
perf = (performance.now() - perf).toFixed(5);
console.log(`map => ${JSON.stringify(finalArr.slice(0, 3))} ... ${perf}ms`);

// forEach
finalArr.length = 0;
perf = performance.now();
arr4Test.forEach(v => finalArr.push(Object.values(v)));
perf = (performance.now() - perf).toFixed(5);
console.log(`forEach => ${JSON.stringify(finalArr.slice(0, 3))} ... ${perf}ms`);
```

Comment: Benchmarked the options and I think the classic loop test is not good, Object.values should be used as well as in the other tests otherwise it's unequal conditions. Added an answer with the benchmark

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Kooilinc's answer. Benchmarked the options and I think the classic loop test is not good, `Object.values` should be used as well as in the other tests otherwise it's unequal conditions:

```html
<script name="benchmark" data-count="1000">

const arr4Test = [...Array(10000)].map((_, i) => ({name: `a`, class: 1, id: i}));
let finalArr = [];

// @benchmark for...off
finalArr.length = 0;
for (let obj of arr4Test) {
  finalArr.push(Object.values(obj));
}
finalArr;

// @benchmark classic loop
finalArr.length = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr4Test.length; i += 1) {
  let tmpArr = [];
  
  for (let key in arr4Test[i]) {
    tmpArr.push(arr4Test[i][key])
  }
  
  finalArr.push(tmpArr);
}
finalArr;

// @benchmark map
finalArr = arr4Test.map(Object.values);
finalArr;

// @benchmark forEach
finalArr.length = 0;
arr4Test.forEach(v => finalArr.push(Object.values(v)));
finalArr;

</script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/silentmantra/benchmark/master/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to push a new array to `finalArr` using `.map` and the order you want of the columns.

```
let arr = [
    { 'name' : 'a', 'class':'7', 'id':'1' },
    { 'name' : 'b', 'class':'7', 'id':'2' },
    { 'name' : 'b', 'class':'7', 'id':'3' },
    { 'name' : 'd', 'class':'7', 'id':'4' }
    ]
    
let finalArr = [];

arr.map(row => {
  finalArr.push([row.name, row.id, row.class]);
})

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: If you don't use the return value of `map()`, you should use `forEach()` instead. So either `arr.forEach(row => finalArr.push([row.name, row.id, row.class]))` or `finalArr = arr.map(row => [row.name, row.id, row.class])`. Do not use `map()` just for iteration purposes, that's not what it's designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let th = ['name', 'id', 'class']

let arr = [{
    'name': 'a',
    'class': '7',
    'id': '1'
  },
  {
    'name': 'b',
    'class': '7',
    'id': '2'
  },
  {
    'name': 'b',
    'class': '7',
    'id': '3'
  },
  {
    'name': 'd',
    'class': '7',
    'id': '4'
  }
];

let data = arr.map((e) => ([e.name, e.id, e.class]));
console.log(data);

let data1 = arr.map((e) => th.map((j) => e[j]))
console.log(data1);

console.log(arr.map((e) => (Object.values(e))));
```